# How to set stock to 0 before product import?

Tags: commerce

I want to set the stock of every product with label X to 0 before I do a product import. This to make sure items with label X that are not in the CSV file, have stock 0 (and are disabled) because we don't have them in stock anymore (= sold in the physical shop).

Label X is a taxonomy term which I use it to determine if the product is new collection or outlet.

But I can't get a working Rule that does that. Can anyone help me out?

I allready tried the Commerce Feeds patch to Disable/Unpublish Commerce Product if non-existant in feed (https://www.drupal.org/node/2454175) but that does not work for me.

Comment: An alternative rule can be "after importing feed" disable all products with label X that where not in the feed. But I also don't get that working. Can't find the conditions.